# how to apply the css style only to child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to apply the css style only to child of the ul not to the grand children of ul.
But here i can't do it help me to do this, Thanks in advance.
[I have tried here](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/vY6RG/)

My html is here

```
<div class="list">

<ul>
   <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/BiiwC.jpg" /></li>
   <li>
       <ul>
           <li><h3>Photos</h3></li>
           <li><p>See more photos</p></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BiiwC.jpg" /></li>
   <li>
       <ul>
           <li><h3>Video</h3></li>
           <li><p>Watch video</p></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
```

My Css is here

`.list ul li{float:left;list-style:none;}​`

Comment: Try http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did u try this?

```
.list ul>li{float:left ;list-style:none ; }
.list ul li ul li{float:none!important;list-style:none !important; }
```

Here is the demo
http://jsfiddle.net/vY6RG/4/

Comment: i have tried that it is not working here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/vY6RG/3/

Answer (score 0):

use the `>` selector, e.g. `.list ul > li`

Comment: i have tried that it is not working here is the link jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/vY6RG/3

Comment: no it doesn't. you didn't put a `>` between `.list` and `ul`, so it'll select both levels of `ul`, and therefore both levels of `li`, even despite the `>`. You need to have two `>` selectors in there.